# Adding a string to an ArrayList of strings in the JFrame after the button is pressed

Tags: java, arrays, swing, button, jframe

I have a programming problem with my JFrame. I want my GUI program to add single String values to the ArrayList after the user presses the button "ACCEPT". I have written several lines of code, but now I have reached the "dead end" and have no idea how to finish it. At the moment I am experiencing a problem with line "first_names.add(firstName);".

```
public class Card extends JFrame {

    private JTextField firstName;
    private JTextField lastName;
    private JTextField amount;
    private JButton accept;

    public Card() {
        super("Cash Machine");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        firstName = new JTextField("Enter your first name here");
        firstName.setEditable(true);
        add(firstName);

        lastName = new JTextField("Enter your last name here");
        add(lastName);

        amount = new JTextField("Enter amount here");
        add(amount);

        accept = new JButton("Accept");
        add(accept);

        newHandler handler = new newHandler();
        firstName.addActionListener(handler);
        lastName.addActionListener(handler);
        amount.addActionListener(handler);
        accept.addActionListener(handler);

    }
}

private class newHandler implements ActionListener {

    ArrayList<String> first_names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> last_names = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if(event.getSource()==firstName) {
            first_names.add(firstName);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What is the error? can you share the log?

Answer (score 0):

try firstName.getText()

```
first_names.add(firstName.getText())
```

Answer (score 0):

After a cursory look at your code, one thing seems to jump out. You have parameterized your ArrayList with the type String. This line:

```
 first_names.add(firstName);
```

adds this object:

```
private JTextField firstName;
```

which is in fact not a String, but a JTextField!

Try instead `firstName.getText()`, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This line seems wrong:

```
first_names.add(firstName);
```

`first_names` is an `ArrayList` of `Strings`, so you must give it a `String` when doing `add()`.  The `getText()` method does returns the `String` for `firstName`:

```
first_names.add(firstName.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add only one action listner. Here is a code that may help you.

```
private JTextField firstName; 
private JTextField lastName;
private JTextField amount;
private JButton accept;
private ArrayList<String> first_names = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> last_names = new ArrayList<String>();

public Card() {
    super("Cash Machine");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    firstName = new JTextField("Enter your first name here");
    firstName.setEditable(true);
    add(firstName);

    lastName = new JTextField("Enter your last name here");
    add(lastName);

    amount = new JTextField("Enter amount here");
    add(amount);

    accept = new JButton("Accept");
    add(accept);

    //ONE LISTENER
    accept.addActionListener(handler);

}

private class newHandler implements ActionListener {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    //Adding textField values to your lists
        first_names.add(firstName.getText());
        last_names.add(lastName.getText())


    }


}
```

Comment: It seems he adds an ActionListner to ALL his component, which is wrong.